# Angular testing stateprovider always returns null

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm using Karma to write angular tests: Here's my spec.js file:

```
'use strict';
var state;
var $rootScope, $state, $injector, CategoriesService;

describe('Categories', function() {
describe('Categories Manage', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
       beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
       module('CL.Categories', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('CategoriesService', CategoriesService = {});
        });

        inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache, _CategoriesService_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $state = _$state_;
            $injector = _$injector_;
            CategoriesService = _CategoriesService_;

            // We need add the template entry into the templateCache if we ever
            // specify a templateUrl
            $templateCache.put('layout/dashboard.html', '');
            $templateCache.put('layout/sidebar.html', '');
            $templateCache.put('layout/footer.html', '');
            $templateCache.put('layout/header.html', '');
            $templateCache.put('categories/manage/index.html', '');

        });
    });

    it('should respond to URL with query parameters', function() {
        expect($state.href(state)).toEqual('#/categories/manage');
    });
});
```

});

This is my config file :

```
(function (){
'use strict';

angular.module('CL.Categories')
    .config(['$stateProvider', categoriesConfig]);

function categoriesConfig ($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard.selectCategories', {
            url: "/categories/select?criteria&referrer&index",
            templateUrl: 'categories/select/index.html',
            controller: 'SelectCategoriesController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                categoryRoot: ['CategoriesService', function(CategoriesService){
                    return CategoriesService.getRootCategories();
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('dashboard.manageCategories', {
            url: "/categories/manage?active",
            templateUrl: 'categories/manage/index.html',
            controller: 'ManageCategoriesController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            resolve: {
                workCategories: ['CategoriesService', function (CategoriesService) {
                    return CategoriesService.getCategoriesByOrganisationWithCertificates();
                }]
            }
        });
}
})();
```

in my karma.config file I have the base path set to **'./'**. the test expect($state.href(state)) always returns null

Answer (score 0):

When you're making your mock call for state, try this instead to get the 'state':

```
state = $state.get('dashboard.selectCategories');
```

Then you can test pieces of the state declaration:

```
expect(state.url).toEqual('/categories/select?criteria&referrer&index');
expect(state.templateUrl).toEqual('categories/select/index.html');
```

And so on...

Comment: I have tried placing the $state.get statement in the inject function, the outer beforeEach and above the it statement, and always state is null

Comment: I have had to move the declaration of the variables above the outer describe, but it doesn't matter where in the cycle I try any of '$state.go', '$state.get' or '$state.transitionTo' I always have returned `no such state.`

Comment: Move the $state.get() statement into the it() statement. Personally I would wrap each 'state' test in it's own describe block, with it's own beforeEach() block etc.,

Comment: state is still null :( It's almost as if it's not picking up the config file as a reference point.

Comment: You may have to do angular.mock.module('ui.router'); (and import it too)

Comment: I've done that and amended the code above to show where i've placed it, still no joy.

Comment: I've also tried to place a spyOn($state, 'go') and calling digest on rootScope to force the state, but still makes no difference